# Hive 3.1 "timestamp with local time zone" problem

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, create-table, timestamp-with-timezone

we try to use Hive 3.1.1 "timestamp with local time zone" feature, but when we try to create table like this:

```
create table t3
(ts timestamp with local time zone)
stored as parquet
location '/data/t3';
```

we get the error:
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown field type: timestamp with local time zone('Europe/Moscow')`
i.e. Hive determine time zone correctly, but  can not create table with such type of field.

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Normalize timestamp (convert to UTC) using `to_utc_timestamp`

```
to_utc_timestamp(timestamp_column,'Europe/Moscow')
```

And store it as `timestamp`

Comment: Good one @leftjoin